# Inventory Management in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, list

Is there a way to do Inventory Management (for Goods which are bought & sold) in SharePoint 2010 ?.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you be more specific? Inventory that is being bought/sold or an inventory of sites?

Comment: for Goods which are bought & sold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is still a little vague, but this sounds like it could be highly transactional. In my opinion something like this would be better implemented in a relational database.  I am not saying that it couldn't be built in SharePoint, just that you might want to consider a traditional database approach.

Comment: We have a very large Purchase Division & equally large Sales Division across different cities. What we want is to handle all accounts of Goods bought & sold in SharePoint itself. So I was searching for such possibility.

Comment: Yeah, so in my opinion, I would probably use a SQL database on the back end.  You could use SharePoint to surface the data either through a custom UI, external lists, or BCS.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you could do some light inventory management through SharePoint natively. Basically you would create a workflow that would deduct from a number field. If you were doing something very large scale, you would probably want to consider customizing a solution, but for a small internal "store" you would be able to do this.